# Accessing a string in a dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, nsdictionary, plist

How can I access a string in a dictionary in a dictionary in a plist file?
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: arrayname ofType:@"plist"];
WordsDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];

words = [WordsDic allKeys];

insidedic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[words objectAtIndex:0] ]];;
level2 = [insidedic allKeys];
```

then i tried this but I got an error

```
for (NSString *parent in words) {

        insidedic = [WordsDic objectForKey:parent];
        level2 = [insidedic allKeys];

        NSLog(@"%@", level2);
    }
```

Comment: do you know the key of the dictionary and the string??

Comment: Use NSLog(@"WordsDic: %@", WordsDic); Then you will get dictionary formation.

Comment: "ok then what i should do ?"  Write code to extract the data you want.  Rather than asking someone else to do your homework for you.

Comment: that is a good idea, i followed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
for (NSString *key in [wordsDic allKeys]) {
   NSDictionary *secondLevel = [wordsDic objectForKey:key];
   for (NSString *secondLevelKey in [secondLevel allKeys]) {
      NSLog(@"%@",[secondLevel objectForKey:secondLevelKey]);
   }
}
```

In your code, "level2" is an array, not a string so will crash with that NSLog statement.

Comment: Thank u very very much u r answer was so helpful i did it :)